# How can I stop my mascara smudging?

Tags: makeup

I wear mascara, and sometimes it seems to smudge - not for any reason, some days it does, some days it doesn't.

I have tried changing brands, and applying less mascara, but the brand change didn't help, and less didn't look as good.

[image]

*[Masterfile, Robert Karpa](http://www.masterfile.com/stock-photography/image/700-00194277/Portrait-of-Woman-with-Smudged-Make-Up)*

How can I prevent smudged mascara?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using waterproof mascara?

Comment: A lot irritate my eyes due to the amount of work you have to do to get it off.

Answer (score 3):

It may be caused by oily eyelids - naturally oily or due to use of eye cream. Some girls put a small amount of translucent powder. Powder keep the eyelid dry for a longer time. But don't put too much powder